# Incrementing Bootstrap progress bar percentage based on number of elements to loop through

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

With jQuery, I'm trying to increment part of a Bootstrap progress bar based on how many elements in a JS array it has to loop though and do an AJAX request for.

My plan is to get the length of the array, divide the total percent of the progress bar to get through (60% in the case) and divide that by the length to get how much percent each loop should increment by.

My code so far is:

```
function savedata(qid) {

      var answerslen = choiceoptions.length;

     //We have 60% of the bar to clear looping these, so work out increment
     var proginc = 60 / answerslen;

     choiceoptions.forEach(function(entry) { //Loop through array

         $.ajax({
             method: "post",
             url: "/../save",
             data: { qid: qid, answer: entry }
         })
        .done(function( msg ) {

          var curprog = ( 100 * parseFloat($('#progressbar').css('width')) / parseFloat($('#progressbar').parent().css('width')) );

          var newprog = parseInt(curprog) + parseInt(proginc);

          $("#progressbar").css('width', newprog);


        });

    });

}
```

This doesn't work as desired, and instead sends the progress straight off to over 100% on the first loop. Can anyone help me achieve this?

Many thanks

Codeine which may help: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEXOJP?editors=1010

Comment: Can you post an example in jsfiddle or snippet or codepen?

Comment: @silviagreen Can I do that with the AJAX calls etc though? I'll try now.

Comment: Here you go: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEXOJP?editors=1010

Comment: I'd advice using echo checks. Basically, use `alert(variable)` or `console.log(variable)` and check every single variable used from the bottom to the top to trim down the error possibilities. Then, you can figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: I don't understand,  the bar starts from zero and for each element of the array you fill the bar to reach 100%?

Comment: How about that? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obKRvq?editors=0010

Comment: @silviagreen No, the bar starts at 20, and needs to get to 80 in steps dependent on how many elements are in the array.

Comment: @samiles look at this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyzeqo?editors=0010

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I'd do it:

If you're progress bar is already at 60% (or .6, or 60) in the example, that means you have 40% (or .4, or 40) to go. I'm assuming you have either 40 more questions or at least some number of questions left that is divisible by 2, 4, 5, 8, or 10 of your remaining amount; this value would be attributed to the entry variable you have above. If this is the case, the basic formula to find the current progress bar width amount would be ((60 + amount the "entry" is worth)/100)*100.

No need to derive the current progress bar width since the math to find the percentage in this case is fairly simple. [Look here for a refresher course on percentages formulas.](http://www.helpingwithmath.com/by_subject/percentages/per_calculating.htm)